# Minimizing the Frobenius norm of a quadratic matrix expression

Tags: matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, non-convex-optimization

Given matrices $R \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $Y \in \mathbb R^{p \times n}$, where $R$ is full rank, how can I solve the following optimization problems?

$$\min_{X \in \mathbb R^{p \times m}} \| X R R^T X^T -Y Y^T \|_F \tag{1}$$
or
$$\min_{X \in \mathbb R^{p \times m}} \| X R R^T X^T -Y Y^T \|_2 \tag{2}$$

Also, $R$ is the matrix of the m rows in $Y$.
I am guessing the solution of $(1)$ could be $X=YR^+$, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Are you assuming the solution is unique? If you square the norm and find where the gradient vanishes, you should obtain a cubic matrix equation.

Comment: Thank you! Details about dimensions added!

Comment: What does it mean to say that a non-square matrix is full rank? Fat? Full row rank? Tall?  Full column rank?

Comment: I always understand full rank as "rank as large as possible".

Comment: @Dirk Doesn't everyone?

Comment: What is $R^+$ in $X=YR^+$?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I assume it is the pseudoinverse of $R$, but I am not the OP.